# Mockito failing basic example

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I'm new to mockito so I'm trying to learn with some basic examples.

Here is my service.

```
public class MyCoolServiceImpl implements MyCoolService{

    public String getName() {
        return "String from service";
    }

}
```

`MyCoolService` is just an interface

```
public interface MyCoolService {

    public String getName();
}
```

And I have a simple use case:

```
public class SomeUseCase {
    private MyCoolService service = new MyCoolServiceImpl();

    public String getNameFromService(){
        return service.getName();
    }
}
```

Mothing complicated. So I write my test class as follows:

```
public class SomeUseCaseTest {
    @Mock
    MyCoolService service;

    SomeUseCase useCase = new SomeUseCase();

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        initMocks(this);

        when(service.getName()).thenReturn("String from mockito");
    }


    @Test
    public void getNameTest(){

        String str = useCase.getNameFromService();

        assertEquals("String from mockito", str);
    }
}
```

So, as I understand, `str` should contains `"String from mockito"`, since I'm telling mockito to return that string when `service.getName()` is called, however my test fails because it returns `"String from service"`.

What am I missing here? Did I misunderstood how mockito works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell `mockito` where to inject the created mock. In your case you just have to use `@InjectMocks` annotation:

```
public class SomeUseCaseTest {
    @Mock
    MyCoolService service;

    @InjectMocks
    SomeUseCase useCase = new SomeUseCase();

    ....
}
```